# What is the minimum amount of transactions required to approve a new transaction?

Tags: transaction

The official IOTA FAQ mentions how Bitcoin needs roughly 6 blocks to verify a new transaction. What is the equivalent rough estimate for IOTA in order to verify a single new transaction? How big of a subtangle does a node need to verify a new transaction?

Answer (score 3):

In IOTA, we don't have blocks.

Each transaction in the Tangle approves two previous transactions.

A confirmed transaction is one that is approved by the Coordinator.

You can read more about the Coordinator in the [developer documentation](https://docs.iota.org/docs/getting-started/0.1/network/the-coordinator).